# Swift Codable struct for non constant value

Tags: swift, struct, codable

I have a json that one part of it is not constant and I don't know how to do the Codable struct.
Please see the example code under:

The fruits part is not constant so I'm not sure how to do the Codable struct. I tried to find answer on SOF but I can't find any for "non constant json Codable struct". I might not searching the correct key words.

Thank you.

Here is the example of the json:

```
{
"success": true,
"username": "app",
"data": {
    "locations": {
        "asia": {
            "japan": {
                "store_count": 5
            },
            "korea": {
                "store_count": 3
            }
        }
    },
    "market": {
        "fruits": {
            "banana": {
                "price": 50.00,
                "count": 2
            },
            "apple": {
                "price": 444.00,
                "count": 16
            },
            "mango": {
                "price": 28.00,
                "count": 1
            },
            "peach": {
                "price": 50.00,
                "count": 2
            },
            "watermelon": {
                "price": 50.00,
                "count": 2
            },
            "blackberry": {
                "price": 57.00,
                "count": 2
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Struct for the json

```
struct Markets: Codable {
    let success: Bool?
    let data: Data?

    struct Data: Codable {
        let locations: Locations
        let market: Market

        struct Locations: Codable {
            let asia: Asia

            struct Asia: Codable {
                let japan: Stores
                ler korea: 
            }

                struct Stores: Codable {
                    let store_count: Int
                }
        }

            struct Market: Codable {
               var fruits: Type

               struct Type: Codable {
                    // the fruits type are not constant.  
                   
               }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the struct that is consistent:

```
struct FruitInfo: Codable {
    var price: Double
    var count: Int
}
```

And map those to String:

```
var fruits: [String: FruitInfo]
```

There are many other solutions if you want another type of structure (for example embedding the name of the fruit into the struct), but this is the simplest, and requires no custom `init`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import Foundation

// MARK: - Test
struct Test: Codable {
    let success: Bool
    let username: String
    let data: DataClass
}

// MARK: - DataClass
struct DataClass: Codable {
    let locations: Locations
    let market: Market
}

// MARK: - Locations
struct Locations: Codable {
    let asia: Asia
}

// MARK: - Asia
struct Asia: Codable {
    let japan, korea: Japan
}

// MARK: - Japan
struct Japan: Codable {
    let storeCount: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case storeCount = "store_count"
    }
}

// MARK: - Market
struct Market: Codable {
    let fruits: Fruits
}

// MARK: - Fruits
struct Fruits: Codable {
    let banana, apple, mango, peach: Apple
    let watermelon, blackberry: Apple
}

// MARK: - Apple
struct Apple: Codable {
    let price, count: Int
}
```

from https://app.quicktype.io/

simply enter your json and it gives you either class or struct